# Blogger connectivity error on Live Writer & Scribefire, Zoundry Raven

Tags: blogger, live, writer

Unable to connect to Blogger via - Zoundry, Scribefire and Live Writer. There's a hell lot of questions and issues going on blogger support forums but seems google is not looking at it. It all started yesterday on 26th May 2015. Please advise if their is any workaround or how to change the scribefire API or code to make it Google's new OAuth Compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google and Microsoft worked together and resolved the issue for Windows Live Writer. But it's still persists for Scribefire. Scribefire team has to update OAuth login code.